# Filter data within datagridview bounded from DataSet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, .net-4.0

I have bounded data to `datagridview` from `DataSet`and  I am trying to filter 
these bounded data within `datagridview` on event of `textchange` 
I got two issues when

1. I start typing it work fine except it delete the custom `datagridview` headers and set the name of columns query ex. Header is 'First Name' it replaced by 'NAM' which is the column name at database...
2. Second issue when I came into else part it wont re-bounded and throw an Exception what I have missed ?

   ```
   public DataSet GetPatientList()
   {
       string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRJDconnstr"].ToString();
       string cmdStr = @"SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS SEQ,
                                                ID,
                                                DocNUM,
                                                NAM,
                                                FNAME,
                                                LFNAME,
                                                PHONE,
                                                MOBILE,
                                                SEX,
                                                BIRTHDAY,
                                                ADDRESS,
                                                ENDATETIME
                                           FROM SICK
                                    ORDER BY ENDATETIME ASC;";

       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
       {
               conn.Open();
               cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

               ds = new DataSet();
               da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

               da.Fill(ds, "PatientList");

               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_RowNum"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["SEQ"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_PatientID"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["ID"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_DocNUM"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["DocNUM"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_FirstName"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["NAM"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_FatherName"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["FNAME"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_LastName"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["LFNAME"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_Phone"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["PHONE"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_Mobile"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["MOBILE"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_Gender"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["SEX"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_Birthday"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["BIRTHDAY"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_Address"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["ADDRESS"].ColumnName;
               DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_EntryDate"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["ENDATETIME"].ColumnName;

               return ds;
       }
   }
   ```

Text Change event

```
    private void TB_FirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstName.Text))
        {
            // first try below
            (ds.Tables["PatientList"] as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
            // second try below
            //ds.Tables["PatientList"].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            DGV_PatientList.DataSource = GetPatientList();
            DGV_PatientList.DataSource = ds.Tables["PatientList"].DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @MrZander Object reference not set to an instance of an object on line `                    DGV_PatientList.Columns["DGV_PatientList_RowNum"].DataPropertyName = ds.Tables["PatientList"].Columns["SEQ"].ColumnName;
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false.

That is what is causing the names to change, and also why you are getting the exception.  The columns don't exist anymore and you are referencing them by name.

Comment: thanks it works now but there is strange issue happening not all textbox are textchange event are working !

Comment: thanks it works now but there is strange issue happening not all textbox are textchange event are working !

Answer (score 1):

Working with DataGridView bound to a dataset isn't supposed to be this hard - you must have been following a really old, or poorly written tutorial

The way this is all supposed to hang together is much more neat and compact:

```
//in your code that handles loading the grid with data, e.g. in a Load button handler

  patientListTableAdapter.Fill(ds.PatientList); //strongly typed dataset, table is already bound to grid in design time. 
//Visual Studio binds it fully for you when you add it to the form, in the designer
//you never again mess with the bindings, just fill and empty the table: MVC


private void TB_FirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){

  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstName.Text)
    patientListBindingSource.Filter = null;
  else
    patientListBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("NAM LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstName.Text);
}
```

Yes... just 5 lines of code should be doing everything you're trying to achieve here. Right now, you're using these technologies in an incorrect way, and achieving a difficult and poor performing result.

For guidance on how you should be using datatables, refer to MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx

Start with the "Creating a Simple Data Application" walk through, make a new project, follow th steps and create a new sample app. After you've done that, i recommend coming back to the existing app and making NO attempts to salvage what has already been done - delete the lot, remove the datagridview from the form, create a new typed dataset, link it to your DB, drop a new correctly bound datagridview on your form and th designer will set everything up. Then all you need to do is pick a suitable place to load it with data, and apply a textchanged handler (the 5 lines of code I put above)

I know it's going to be hard, throwing away all that code you poured blood weat and tears into.. but it will always be a headache, and never work right, because it's plain up the wrong way to go about working with data and bound controls